# GWT add two button to a Cell<> element

Tags: java, button, gwt, grid, gxt

I have a GWT project. I have a ColumnEditor window where can i edit a table's columns. I want to add two button to a cell in ColumnEditor. Every column in ColumnEditor represented by a ColumnConfig, like this :

```
ColumnConfig<ColumnDataModel, String> moveField = new ColumnConfig<ColumnDataModel, String>(properties.button(), 40, "");
moveField.setCell(moveUp);
```

I want to use the moveup cell with 2 button. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CompositeCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html) to combine many cells into one.

First build two [ButtonCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html)s and then combine them into one cell by passing a list of `ButtonCell`s to `CompositeCell`'s constructor.